# Fastest way to build a graph of called functions and objects

Tags: c++, graph, gdal

I have task to remove all unused code from a third-party library. That is, I have a function that calls several other functions and objects, which in turn also call something. In particular, I'm talking about the GDAL library, I only need one function from there, and I don't want to increase the source code of my program tenfold.
I've tried using the "breadth-first search" similarity to go through all the functions (in my head), but the complexity of this is growing very quickly.
The question is, what is the fastest way to build a graph of called functions and objects and remove unnecessary ones?

Comment: if you remove all, the compiler can tell what is missing

Comment: With appropriate flags, linker can remove unused functions. (there are still unreached functions though). for gcc: [`-Wl,-static -fvtable-gc -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-s`](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2003-08/msg00128.html)